# В поселке Смедович или поселке Смедовиче?

Tags: имена-собственные

Как правильно написать: "В поселке Смедович" или "в поселке Смедовиче"?

Answer (score 1):

Согласно строгой литературной норме географическое название, употреблённое с родовыми наименованиями *город, посёлок, хутор, река* и др., выступающее в функции приложения, согласуется с определяемым словом, то есть склоняется. Ни в одну категорию исключений из этого правила ваш топоним не входит. Поэтому правильное употребление: *в поселке Смедовиче*.